# Unix shell scripting: pass shell options (-x etc.) to nested scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, posix

How can I run nested shell scripts with the same option?  For example,

`parent.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
./child.sh
```

`child.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
ls
```

How can I modify `parent.sh` so that when I run it with `sh -x parent.sh`, the `-x` option is effective in `child.sh` as well and the execution of `ls` is displayed on my console?

I'm looking for a portable solution which is effective for rare situations such as system users with `/bin/false` as their registered shell.  Will the `$SHELL` environment variable be of any help?

Clarification: I sometimes want to call `parent.sh` with `-x`, sometimes with `-e`, depending on the situation.  So the solution must not involve hard-coding the flags.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `bash`, i can recommend the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SHELLOPTS
./child.sh
```

You can propagate as many times as you need, also you can use `echo $SHELLOPTS` in every script down the line to see what is happening and how options are propagated if you need to understand it better.

But for `/bin/sh` it will fail with `/bin/sh: SHELLOPTS: readonly variable` because of how POSIX is enforced on `/bin/sh` in various systems, more info here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-10/msg00052.html

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like a hack and seems it's not the best way.
But it will do exact what you want

One of the ways how you can do it - it's  to create aliases to create wrappers for `sh`:

```
alias saveShell='cp /bin/sh $some_safe_place'

alias shx='cp $some_safe_place /bin/x_sh; rm /bin/sh; echo "/bin/x_sh -x $@" > /bin/sh; chmod 755 /bin/sh '

alias she='cp $some_safe_place /bin/e_sh; rm /bin/sh; echo "/bin/e_sh -e $@" > /bin/sh; chmod 755 /bin/sh '
alias restoreShell='cp  $some_safe_place /bin/sh'
```

*How to Use:*
run `saveShell` and then use `shx` or `she` , if you would change `-x` on `-e` run `restoreShell` and then run `shx` or `she` 
run script as usually
sh ./parent.sh

**BE VERY CAREFUL WITH MOVING SH**

Other solution
replace `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -x` or  `#!/bin/sh -e` with `sed` in all sh files before running script.

Comment: I enjoyed your post so much :-)